# Parallel Foreach with a Lazy Loaded List

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am using Entity Framework, and I have a list that I need to iterate through to do work on. I'm unable to do this work directly via the query on the database, and the list can be quiet big, so I'm hoping I can use Parallel Foreach or AsParallel.

The problem is that even when I load my list using ToList() into memory, and then run it in a parallel function, it destroys my lazy loaded navigation properties.

I am running something simple like this (This has been simplified alot for the purpose of this question):

```
var quoteList = DbContext.Quotes.ToList();

List<QuotesItem> quoteViewItemList = new List<QuotesItem>();

quoteList.ForAll(quote => {
   var quoteViewItem = new QuotesItem();
    quoteViewItem.YearEnding = quote.QuoteService.FirstOrDefault().Yearending; //is SOMETIMES null when it shouldn't be.
    quoteViewItem.Manager  quote.Client.Manager.Name; //IS sometimes null
    quoteViewItem.... = ..... // More processing here
    quoteViewItemList.Add(quoteViewItem);
});
```

the problem is QuoteService seems to be null sometimes even when its not null in the List.

Comment: Isn't `quoteList` a `List<T>`?  If so, it's not going to have a member called `QuoteService`.  Did you mean `quote.QuoteService.....`?

Comment: yes this is a mistake. I am correcting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets talk about the issue.
The only reason i can image is disposing the **DbContext** befour **.ForAll** has finnished its work, probably from different thread ? But i am just guessing at the moment.

I can give you couple of suggestions about possible optimization of the code.
First evaluating all Quotes using **.ToList()** probably has some performance impact if there are many records in the database, so my advice here is to exchange the eager evaluation with SQL cursor.
This can be achieved by using any construct/code which internaly  uses **IEnumerable<>** and more specific **.GetEnumerator()**.

The internal implementation of the IQueriable<> in EF creates a SQL cursor, which is pretty fast. The best part is that you can use it with .AsParallel() or Parallel.ForEach, both internally uses the Enumerators.

This is not very documented feature, but if start SQL Server Profile and execute the code below you will see that only single request is executed to the Server and also you can notice that the RAM of the machine executing the code does not spike, which means it does not fetch everything at once.

I've found some random information about it if you're intrested: https://sqljudo.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/entity-framework-hidden-cursors/

Although i've used this approach in cases where the code operating on the database record was pretty heavy, for simple projection from one type to another running the cursor with `.AsParallel( .. )` or simple `foreach` constuct may perform similar.

So using

```
DbContext.Quotes
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)
.ForAll(...)
```

should run with good performance.

My second advice is about accessing Navigation properties in EF with lazy loading. This as you know leads to the N+1 select issue.
So instead of depending on EF lazy evaluation in this case it will be better to eagerly fetch the navigation properties, so we can rewrite the code about as this

```
 DbContext.Quotes
    .Include(x => x.QuoteService)
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)
    .ForAll(...)
```

This way when accessing the QuoteService navigation property EF won't do any additional requests to the Server, so this should dramatically improve you performance and it probably can magicaly fix the Null reference issue (i hope)

The Generic version of the .Include(..) method which i am using part of the System.Data.Entity namespace.

Further if it acceptable for your scenario you can disable the change tracking which will gain you a bit more performance. So my final code will look like this

```
  var queryViewItems = DbContext.Quotes
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.QuoteService)
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)
            .Select(x => { ... })
            .ToList();
```